# Update and edit image in laravel

Tags: html, laravel

I am trying to edit an image for my admin page, for example here is my MenuController:

```
public function update(Request $request, Menu $menu)
{
    $menu->name = $request->name;
    $menu->description = $request->description;
    $menu->price = $request->price;
    $menu->featured = $request->featured;
    $menu->category_id = $request->category_id;
    $image = $request->file('image');
    if ($image) {
        $image_name = date('dmy_H_s_i');
        $extension = strtolower($image->getClientOriginalExtension());
        $image_full_name = $image_name . '.' . $extension;
        $upload_path = 'public/menu/';
        $image_url = $upload_path . $image_full_name;
        $success = $image->move($upload_path, $image_full_name);

        $image['image'] = $image_url;
        $menu = DB::table('menus')->insert($image);

        return redirect()->route('admin.menu.index');
    };

    $menu->save();

    return redirect()->route('admin.menu.index');
}
```

When I edit, it works just fine with my data. But not with the image. The image won't change to the new one I chose. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

When there is an image and the program enters in the if condition block, You are not actually updating the image column inside your Menu model, but surprisingly attempting to create a new record, which doesn't make any sense to me.

Assuming you just want to update your model and it has an image field as well, your image block should be like:

```
if ($image) {
    $image_name = date('dmy_H_s_i');
    $extension = strtolower($image->getClientOriginalExtension());
    $image_full_name = $image_name . '.' . $extension;
    $upload_path = 'public/menu/';
    $image_url = $upload_path . $image_full_name;
    $success = $image->move($upload_path, $image_full_name);

    // Update the image field in your Menu model.
    $menu->image =  $image_url;
};

// Save the model.
$menu->save();
```

Comment: I did as you suggested but it didn't update the image

Comment: what laravel version do you use? and also, is the naming convention should be as you have specified in your code or Laravel naming convention for uploading files are acceptable as well?

Comment: I use laravel version 8.17.2, and for the naming convention I don't really understand because I'm new to laravel

Answer (score -1):

use hasFile to check if the request has a file

```
if($request->hasFile('image')){
```